# Where's "cache" in react-query(tanStack)? Where do they actually cache the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, react-query

Where is this cache they mention in React Query, is it localStorage/IndexedDB/SessionStorage?
And often they say it's memory which also points to cookies or localStorage.
Where is the location of this "cache"?

If it's called memory then how do we perform CRUD operations on cache data in this memory?(RAM is memory here I assume)

Answer (score 11):

> Where is this cache they mention in React Query, is it localStorage/IndexedDB/SessionStorage? And often they say it's memory which also points to cookies or localStorage. Where is the location of this "cache"?

The cache is a javascript object stored in memory. It will not persist in session storage, local storage, or indexDB unless you add code to do that. If you do want to persist it, [persistQueryClient](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/plugins/persistQueryClient) can help with that.

> how do we perform CRUD operations on cache data

You don't usually need to do anything special; as you make queries and mutations, react query will update the cache for you, and then those updated values are given to your components.

If you need to invalidate the cache for a particular query, you can use the [invalidateQueries](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientinvalidatequeries) method on the query client:

```
await queryClient.invalidateQueries({
  queryKey: ['posts'],
})
```

If for some reason you need access to the cache object itself, you can call `queryClient.getQueryCache()` to get it, and then you'll have access to all the methods listed in [this documentation page](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/QueryCache), such as `find`:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const queryCache = queryClient.getQueryCache();
  const query = queryCache.find({ queryKey: ['posts'] });
  //...
}
```

There's also a cache for mutations, which you can access via `queryClient.getMutationCache()`

Comment: "Object stored in memory" you are mentioning RAM correct?
Am trying to use cache for my application in the client side, I wanna know where exactly is this cache?

Comment: `"Object stored in memory" you are mentioning RAM correct` Yes, random access memory. If you write a line of code that says `const cache = {}`, you are making an object in memory. React-query's cache is the same kind of thing, just a slightly more complicated object.

Comment: this explanation was extremely helpful to me